# How do I change VSCode Python interpreter to Linux terminal on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

so I have been trying to

```
import pandas as pd
```

as well as

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dence, Dropout
```

and

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
```

These are segments of code from my deep learning training data. I have read solutions that I installed pandas and tensorflow on the terminal and that is different than the python running on vscode.

Would appreciate any help as I am new to coding.

Comment: Not true, VSC uses the Python interpreter installed on your system or a virtual environment using that Python interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out which python Interpreter is used in your terminal by calling:

```
which python
```

(or `python3` if you're using Python 3)

In VS Code, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the command `Python: Select Interpreter`:

[image: select interpreter]

Choose the one from the output of the first command. The terminal and VS Code should use the same environment now.